# C++ Remove punctuation from String

Tags: c++, string, parsing, erase, punctuation

I got a string and I want to remove all the punctuations from it. How do I do that? I did some research and found that people use the ispunct() function (I tried that), but I cant seem to get it to work in my code. Anyone got any ideas?

```
#include <string>

int main() {

string text = "this. is my string. it's here."

if (ispunct(text))
text.erase();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check all characters one by one.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i got it.

```
size_t found = text.find('.');
text.erase(found, 1);
```

Comment: This will only erase the first instance of '.', it does not remove all punctuation and not all instances of '.'.

Comment: you should edit your answers to not mislead others. But it also only removes '.'....not all punctuation.

Answer (score 29):

Using algorithm [`remove_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) :-

```
string text,result;
std::remove_copy_if(text.begin(), text.end(),            
                        std::back_inserter(result), //Store output           
                        std::ptr_fun<int, int>(&std::ispunct)  
                       );
```

Answer (score 26):

POW already has a good answer if you need the result as a new string. This answer is how to handle it if you want an in-place update.

The first part of the recipe is `std::remove_if`, which can remove the punctuation efficiently, packing all the non-punctuation as it goes.

```
std::remove_if (text.begin (), text.end (), ispunct)
```

Unfortunately, `std::remove_if` doesn't shrink the string to the new size. It can't because it has no access to the container itself. Therefore, there's junk characters left in the string after the packed result.

To handle this, `std::remove_if` returns an iterator that indicates the part of the string that's still needed. This can be used with strings `erase` method, leading to the following idiom...

```
text.erase (std::remove_if (text.begin (), text.end (), ispunct), text.end ());
```

I call this an idiom because it's a common technique that works in many situations. Other types than `string` provide suitable `erase` methods, and `std::remove` (and probably some other algorithm library functions I've forgotten for the moment) take this approach of closing the gaps for items they remove, but leaving the container-resizing to the caller.

Comment: I just tried that, I get an error: "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Predicate'
remove_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)"

Comment: @moonman239 - my guess is there's more than one implicit cast possible for the predicate - that `remove_if` candidate doesn't exactly limit the options much. Handling of callables has evolved in C++14, C++17 and C++20. Probably use a lambda for the predicate - either in place, or use an `auto` type-inferred variable inintialised using that lambda expression - so no cast-to-callable-object is needed. I've not been coding much recently, though, so if that doesn't help I can only suggest asking a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {

    std::string text = "this. is my string. it's here.";

    for (int i = 0, len = text.size(); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (ispunct(text[i]))
        {
            text.erase(i--, 1);
            len = text.size();
        }
    }

    std::cout << text;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
this is my string its here
```

When you delete a character, the size of the string changes. It has to be updated whenever deletion occurs. And, you deleted the current character, so the next character becomes the current character. If you don't decrement the loop counter, the character next to the punctuation character will not be checked.

Comment: i cant get the ispunct to compile. i have included all the headers you did.

Comment: You have to include either `<ctype.h>` or `<cctype>`.

Answer (score 5):

`ispunct` takes a `char` value not a string.

you can do like

```
for (auto c : string)
     if (ispunct(c)) text.erase(text.find_first_of(c));
```

This will work but it is a slow algorithm.

Comment: text.erase()? are you sure?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty good answer by Steve314.
I would like to add a small change :

```
text.erase (std::remove_if (text.begin (), text.end (), ::ispunct), text.end ());
```

Adding the :: before the function ispunct takes care of overloading .

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that ispunct() takes one argument being a character, while you are trying to send a string. You should loop over the elements of the string and erase each character if it is a punctuation like here:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i<text.length(); ++i)
  if(ispunct(text[i]))
    text.erase(i--, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "this. is my string. it's here.";

    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](char ch)
    {
        if( ispunct(ch) )
            return '\0';
        return ch;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   string s;//string is defined here.

  cout << "Please enter a string with punctuation's: " << endl;//Asking for users input

  getline(cin, s);//reads in a single string one line at a time

/* ERROR Check: The loop didn't run at first because a semi-colon was placed at the end 
                of the statement.  Remember not to add it for loops. */
        for(auto &c : s)  //loop checks every character 
        {       
             if (ispunct(c)) //to see if its a punctuation
              {
               c=' ';       //if so it replaces it with a blank space.(delete) 
              }

        }

        cout <<  s << endl; 


   system("pause");
   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this would be as follows:

```
#include <ctype.h> //needed for ispunct()
string onlyLetters(string str){
    string retStr = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if(!ispunct(str[i])){
            retStr += str[i];
        }
    }
    return retStr;
```

This ends up creating a new string instead of actually erasing the characters from the old string, but it is a little easier to wrap your head around than using some of the more complex built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one, it will remove all the punctuation on the string in the text file oky.

```
str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::ispunct), str.end());
```

please reply if helpful

Answer (score 0):

I tried to apply @Steve314's answer but couldn't get it to work until I came across this note [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) on cppreference.com:

> **Notes**
>
> Like all other functions from `<cctype>`, the behavior of `std::ispunct`
>   is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as
>   `unsigned char` nor equal to EOF. To use these functions safely with
>   plain `char`s (or `signed char`s), the argument should first be converted
>   to `unsigned char`.

By studying the example it provides, I am able to make it work like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "this. is my string. it's here.";
    std::string result;
    text.erase(std::remove_if(text.begin(),
                              text.end(),
                              [](unsigned char c) { return std::ispunct(c); }),
               text.end());
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
```