# How to change each word in a string vector to upper case

Tags: c++, string, vector

I was inquiring about reading a sequence of words and storing the values in a vector. Then proceed to change each word in the vector to uppercase and print the out put with respect to eight word to a line. I think my code is either slow or running infinitely as i can't seem to achieve an output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    vector<string> text;
    while (getline(cin, word)) {
        text.push_back(word);
    }
    for (auto index = text.begin(); index != text.end(); ++index) {
        for ( auto it = word.begin(); it != word.end(); ++it)
            *it = toupper(*it);
        /*cout<< index << " " << endl;*/
    }

    for (decltype(text.size()) i = 0; i != 8; i++)
        cout << text[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Thomas: this is not about how to use toupper, it should be reopened. @dirty_sanchez: your outer `for` loop defines `index` to cycle through `text`, but you never use `index` inside it. The inner loop uses `word`, but `word` is still the last one the user entered. You should change the inner loop so that it uses `index` instead of `word`.

Comment: @FabioTurati OP is explicitly asking how to convert strings to upper case. The duplicate provides good answers to that. If OP has a different question, then they should be asking that question and not this one.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The OP is explicitly asking about how to change each word in a vector of strings to upper case. It also includes breaking the output after every eighth word. This isn't a duplicate (at least of that question).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Fine, I re-opened it. There are plenty of duplicates (except for the eighth word thing.)

Comment: What do you mean by this: " respect to eight word to a line."? Can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: @Marcin the eight word line means that the output should break  off after the eighth word.

Comment: Rather than the first two `for` loops explicitly using iterators, why not learn about ranged-for loops? Rather than using decltype, why not use `auto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as far as I can tell, the idea here is to ignore the existing line structure, and write out 8 words per line, regardless of line breaks in the input data. Assuming that's correct, I'd start by just reading words from the input, paying no attention to the existing line breaks.

From there, it's a matter of capitalizing the words, writing them out, and (if you're at a multiple of 8, a new-line.

I would also use standard algorithms for most of the work, instead of writing my own loops to do the pars such as reading and writing the data. Since the pattern is basically just reading a word, modifying it, then writing out the result, it fits nicely with the `std::transform` algorithm.

Code to do that could look something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string to_upper(std::string in) {
    for (auto &ch : in)
        ch = toupper((unsigned char) ch);
    return in;
}

int main() {
    int count = 0;

    std::transform(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout),
        [&](std::string const &in) {
            char sep = (++count % 8 == 0) ? '\n' : ' ';
            return to_upper(in) + sep;
        });
}
```

We could implement capitalizing each string as a second lambda, nested inside the first, but IMO, that starts to become a bit unreadable. Likewise, we could use `std::tranform` to implement the upper-case transformation inside of `to_upper`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll rewrite my answer here:

Your outer `for` loop defines `index` to cycle through `text`, but you never use `index` inside it. The inner loop uses `word`, but `word` is still the last one the user entered. You should change the inner loop so that it uses `index` instead of `word`, like this:

```
for ( auto it = index->begin(); it != index->end(); ++it)
```

Comment: I regret to inform that it didn't work,  as there were errors in the code at both index.begin() and index.end(). but i used the arrow operator instead and  then proceed to run the script and as stated earlier the output is either slow or running infinitely

Comment: @dirty_sanchez: my bad about the syntax, I've fixed it now, sorry. About the rest: have you tried debugging your code? What is the point where it slows down or hangs? And by the way, what causes the program to slow down, and what to hang? Does it depend on the input? And what is the output, are your strings at least converted to upper case?

Comment: the fact is after typing the words and pressing enter to obtain the uppercase conversion. I have no output at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively an infinite loop:

```
while (getline(cin, word)) {
    text.push_back(word);
}
```

`getline(cin, word)` reads a line (ending in `'\n'`) from stdin, and puts it into `word`. It then returns `cin` itself (which will evaluate to `true` if the read was successful). You seem to be using it to get a space-delimited word, rather than a whole line, but that's not what it does. Since you put it in the condition of the `while`, after you enter a line, it will wait for another line.

This loop only breaks when `getline` fails. For example, by hitting an End of File character. I expect you're using the console and pressing Enter. In that case, you are never causing `getline` to fail. (If you're feeding a file into stdin, it should work.)

The typical solution to this is to have some sort of way of indicating a stop (such as an "Enter an empty line to stop" or "Write \"STOP\" to stop", and then checking for that before inserting the line into the vector). For you, the solution is to read in a SINGLE line, and then break it up into words (for example, using the `sstream` library).

You can detect whether the program is doing actual work (rather than waiting for more input) by viewing your CPU use. In Windows, this is CTRL+SHIFT+ESC -> Performance, and -> Processes to see your program in particular. You will find that the program isn't actually using the CPU (because it's waiting for more input).

You should try inserting print statements into your program to figure out where it gets up to. You will find it never goes past the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer

```
 for (string &str : vec)
    {
        transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](char c) { return std::toupper(c); });
    }
```

Complete working code as example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    string str;

    while (cin >> str)
    {
        vec.push_back(str);
    }

    for (string &str : vec)
    {
        transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](char c)
                  { return toupper(c); });
    }

    for (auto str : vec)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```